# Two copper pipes running up to loft for no reason

Tags: plumbing, attic

So, I’ve been working on removing some old built in wardrobes in our spare room and found some trunking for two copper pipes running all the way from floor to ceiling and into the loft.

We have a combi boiler installed on the ground floor and no water tank in the loft but I’ve traced the pipes down to the ground floor too. I can’t see if they connect to the boiler or anything, and I’ve checked in the loft and found the end of one of the pipes just cut open, but can’t see the other pipe up there at all. I don’t know the history of heating systems in the house but it’s a 1910 build in London.

Im assuming these are feed & return pipes for an old water tank in the loft which has been removed and I should be okay to cut and cap the pipes under the floor in the spare room?

Wanted to check on here first as we do have gas supply in the house and I’m just not 100% sure not knowing the history of what’s been before.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Given the age, it could have been piping for gas lighting.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, didn’t even realise that was a thing! I did manage to find one of the pipes fully cut and open in the loft, but we still run our gas circuit for the combi so I’d hope we would have noticed if we had a leak by now (doesn’t seem like it based on bills and no noise or movement from the pipe at all).

Comment: Unknown if done in the UK, but most gas has chemicals in it to stink(rotten egg smell), that or you watch the house go boom, if you can't tell of a leak.

Comment: I don't know what's common in London - in my area piped gas was always done in black iron, until CSST came along. Propane gas used to be done in copper, but is no longer done that way. I'd expect that a removed water tank is the correct guess, whether that be the typical UK domestic water or an open expansion tank on a hot water cirulating heating system. In any case, more **an obsolete reason** than no reason.

Comment: Yeah @crip659, I think odour is also added in Uk and nothing from the cut pipe / in general around the area so I’m fairly sure at least one of the pipes isn’t gas (not so sure on the pipe I haven’t been able to trace yet). That also begs the question that I don’t know the answer to, but if you have 2 pipes running side by side would they generally be the same supply (i.e gas or water), or would it be common enough to have water and gas pipes running beside one another? - again my guess would have been feed / return, or hot/cold for water at least.

Comment: Gas is usually one pipe that might branch off.  Water is 80% two pipes, except for only if cold water(garden faucet).  Will have usually a hot and cold pipe close together for sinks or a supply and return(in and out) pipe for a tank type system.